# Can we multiply only specific slots in ciphertexts using Microsoft SEAL?

Tags: seal

For example : In a BFV scheme, using BatchEncoder, we have a ciphertext of some numbers [1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0.......] and we have another ciphertext - [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, 0, 0......] and we add the two together.

The output for it would be - [0,0,0,0,0,-6,0.....].

Now, if i just want the values of the first five slots, how do i do that? Is it possible?

Also, is it possible for us to multiply only, let's say, the first 5 slots of a ciphertext with the first 5 slots of another ciphertext?